# Pass an arrays row shown in an NSTableView to another array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, nstableview

I have 2 arrays

```
var messages = [Message]()
var screenMessages = [screenMessage]()
```

I have the messages array items in a NSTableView.. when I press an IBOutlet I would like to pass the items in that row to the screenMessages array to present in another NSTableView.

My NSTableView starts like so..

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
        let result = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier("cell", owner: self) as? secondviewTableCell

        let mess = messages[row]
```

I've tried a number of ways of appending the screenMessages with the messages[row] but I can't put my finger on it. If anyone could demonstrate or point me in the right direction that would be brilliant.

Thank you.

Added more detail:

Screen one looks like so and when pressing the add button it should then pass that data from that row into screen twos tableview..

[image]

Screen two:

[image]

My View for screen one is as:

```
import Firebase
import Cocoa


 var messages = [Message]()
 var screenMessages = [screenMessage]()
class secondVC: NSViewController, NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource {


    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: NSTableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var screenRefreshBtn: NSButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var refreshButton: NSButton!



    var senderImageUrl: String!
    var ref: Firebase!
    var messagesRef: Firebase!

    func setupFirebase() {

        messagesRef = Firebase(url: "https://url.firebaseio.com/screenmessages")

        messagesRef.queryLimitedToLast(25).observeEventType(FEventType.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
            let text = snapshot.value["text"] as? String
            let sender = snapshot.value["senderName"] as? String
            let imageUrl = snapshot.value["profileImageURL"] as? String
            let MediaType = snapshot.value["MediaType"] as! String
            let fileUrl = snapshot.value["fileUrl"] as? String

            let message = Message(text: text, sender: sender, imageUrl: imageUrl, MediaType: MediaType, fileUrl: fileUrl)
            messages.append(message)

            let screenmessage = screenMessage(text: text, sender: sender, imageUrl: imageUrl, MediaType: MediaType, fileUrl: fileUrl)
            screenMessages.append(screenmessage)


            switch MediaType{
                case "TEXT":

                print("text message")

                case "PHOTO":
                print("photo message")



            default:
            print("default")
            }

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })

    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       setupFirebase()


    }

    // MARK: - Table View

    func numberOfRowsInTableView(tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        return messages.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
        let result = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier("cell", owner: self) as? secondviewTableCell

        let mess = messages[row]
        if mess.text() == nil {
            result?.textField?.alphaValue = 0
            result!.sendertextView.stringValue = mess.sender()


            let url = NSURL(string: mess.fileUrl()!)!

            // Download task:
            // - sharedSession = global NSURLCache, NSHTTPCookieStorage and NSURLCredentialStorage objects.
            let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (responseData, responseUrl, error) -> Void in
                // if responseData is not null...
                if let data = responseData{

                    // execute in UI thread
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                        let photo = NSImage(data: data)!

                       result?.mediaPhoto.image = photo

                    })
                }
            }
            task.resume()

        } else {


            result!.textField!.stringValue = mess.text()!
            result!.sendertextView.stringValue = mess.sender()
        }

        return result


    }





    @IBAction func addtablerow(object: NSButton) {

        let row = tableView.rowForView( object as NSView )
        if ( row > -1 ) {


        }
    }
```

And my second screen is:

```
import Cocoa

class screenVC: NSViewController, NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource {

    var addedObserver = false

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: NSTableView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        refreshObs()
        clearObs()
        self.tableView.backgroundColor = NSColor.clearColor()
        if let window = self.view.window {
            // custom window here
            window.level = Int(CGWindowLevelForKey(.FloatingWindowLevelKey))

        } else {
            addedObserver = true
            self.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "view.window", options: [.New, .Initial], context: nil)

        }



    }

    func refreshList(notification: NSNotification){
        self.tableView.alphaValue = 0
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

            self.tableView.reloadData()

        })

        animateViewRefresh()
        tableView.scrollToEndOfDocument(self)
    }

    func numberOfRowsInTableView(tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        return screenMessages.count
    }


    func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
        let result = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier("cell2", owner: self) as? screenviewTableCell

        let mess = screenMessages[row]
        result?.senderLabel.stringValue = mess.sender()
        if mess.text() != nil {
        result?.messageTextView.stringValue = mess.text()!
        let url = NSURL(string: mess.imageUrl()!)!
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (responseData, responseUrl, error) -> Void in

            if let data = responseData{


                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    result?.avatarImage.image = NSImage(data: data)
                })

            }}

        task.resume()

        } else {
            result?.messageTextView.alphaValue = 0

            let mess = screenMessages[row]
            let url = NSURL(string: mess.fileUrl()!)!
            let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (responseData, responseUrl, error) -> Void in

                if let data = responseData{
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

                        let photo = NSImage(data: data)!

                        result?.mediaPhoto.image = photo

                    })
                }
            }

            let url2 = NSURL(string: mess.imageUrl()!)!

            let task2 = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url2) { (responseData, responseUrl, error) -> Void in

                if let data = responseData{

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                        result?.avatarImage.image = NSImage(data: data)

                    })

                }}
            task.resume()
            task2.resume()




        }

        return result


    }

    // MARK : Animate

     func animateView(notification: NSNotification){
        NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({ (context) in
            context.duration = 2
            self.tableView.animator().alphaValue = 0
            screenMessages.removeAll()
            }, completionHandler: { () -> Void in



        })}

    func animateViewRefresh(){


        NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({ (context) in
            context.duration = 4


            self.tableView.animator().alphaValue = 1

            }, completionHandler: { () -> Void in



        })}

    func refreshObs(){
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(screenVC.refreshList(_:)), name:"refreshMyTableView", object: nil)


    }

    func clearObs(){
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(screenVC.animateView(_:)), name:"clearMyTableView", object: nil)

    }

    override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
        if let window = self.view.window {
            // custom window here
            window.level = Int(CGWindowLevelForKey(.FloatingWindowLevelKey))
            window.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
            window.movableByWindowBackground  = true
            window.opaque = true
            window.backgroundColor = NSColor.clearColor()


        }
    }

    deinit {
        if addedObserver {
            self.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "view.window")
        }
    }



}
```

I have tried a number of things such as 'screenMessages += messages(row)' and appending to add that row to the screenMessages array but I've had no luck.

Am I going about this in the right way or is there a better way of doing so?

Thank you.

Comment: So you want to take an index from the `messages` array and insert it at the same index of the `screenMessages` array? If not, can you provide further clarification? Your question is kinda vague.

Comment: You can copy an entire array by just:
let screenMessages = messages
but not sure if that is what you mean

Comment: I've edited my question to be more clear on what I'm trying to achieve. - I want pass 1 selected rows data from an NSTableView to another NSTableView in another window.

Answer (score 0):

To append an element from one array to another array just write

```
let index = index of element you need
let message = messages[index]
screenMessages.append(message)
```

If message is not the same type as the contents of the screenMessages array you will need to convert it, I would need more details of the types to help with that.

If you are having trouble passing the data to another ViewController I would need more information on the current architecture to give good advice, but for example you might define a protocol MessageDelegate that one of the controllers implements and the other has as a property.

**update**

If you update your data array for a table and want the new information to appear remember to call reloadData on the UITableView

Comment: I've added my code - I want to be able to select which rows from the tableview are shown in the second tableview so not copy all the array but only the row/s that i select by pressing the add IBOutlet.

Comment: I have updated my answer to show how to add an element from one array to another array. Just make index the row you want to transfer.

Comment: That looks right.. Thank you! So I'm trying to get the index of the result, normally in iOS it would be as simple as ItemAtIndexPath but in OSX its ViewForTableColumn - I'm wanting to get the messages array at index right?

Comment: You can get the index of the selected row with the selectedRow property of the NSTableView. If you are not using the built in selection handling you can simply store the row as part of the cell view: add a property to the secondviewTableCell class and store the row id when you create it.

Comment: If you need more detail on that it is best to open a separate question for it, so as not to mix multiple issues in one question :)